# Rails activity feed from a polymorphic following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm tracking the following tables:

```
Story (id, user_id, content)
Vote  (id, user_id, story_id)
Flag  (id, user_id, story_id)
etc..
```

with an activity table:

```
Activity (id, user_id,action, trackable_id, trackable_type)
```

The relationship table:

```
Relationship (id, follower_id, followed_id)
```

I'm currently getting the activities from users a user is following like this:

```
def get_activity_from_followers(current_user)
     followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids})",
          user_id: user.id)
end
```

My question is, how do i get the activities where the the trackable table(e.g. story,vote,flag) belongs to you. 
So right now i'm getting things like:

1. "someone you are following" posted a story
2. "someone you are following" voted a story

i want to also get things like:

1. "someone you are not following" voted your story
2. "someone you are not following" flagged your story

How do I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)?  A scope encapsulates an active record query, or a part of a query.  Scopes are composable, so you can have a few where clauses in a model, some commonly used joins in another, and stick them together as needed.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. That's interesting, how do i go about using that in this situation?

Comment: That's the answer I want to write, if I find time.  I'll need to create a rails project with a simularcrum of your project in order to work that out.  I don't know when I'll get time to try that; I hoped the comment would be useful to you, or another answerer, in the mean time.

Comment: I've never worked with polymorphic associations before.  My attempts to guess at the model definitions are not going well.  Would it be too much trouble for you to add minimal model definitions to the question?  If you can, please show just the bare minimum needed to define the relevant associations between these tables.

Comment: Could you do me a favor and post your class definitions, with just the relationships? I definitely can assist.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have following class definitions and associations:

```
# User 
class User  :trackable
end

# Flag  (id, user_id, story_id)
class Flag  :trackable
end

# with an activity table:
# Activity (id, user_id,action, trackable_id, trackable_type)
class Activity  true
end

# The relationship table:
# Relationship (id, follower_id, following_id)
class Relationship  "User"
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Now, Lets find activities of the users to whom you follow:

```
# List activities of my followings
Activity.where(:user_id => current_user.followings)
```

Listing my activities

```
current_user.activities
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I'd search into Activity using votes and flags id's instead of user id's. Something like this:

```
def get_votes(current_user)
 stories = current_user.stories
 votes = Votes.where(story_id: stories.map {|s| s.id})
 activity = Activity.where(action: 'vote', trackable_id: votes.map{|v| v.id})
end
```

I madre some assumptions. First that you can call `user.stories`, and then that in Activity model 'action' can be vote or flag and that trackable_id relates to Vote and Flag id. If that's not correct, you can get the general idea anyways.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What about making Activity STI class?

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
  belongs_to :user
end

class Vote < Activity
  def to_partial_path
    'users/vote'
  end
end

class Flag < Activity
  def to_partial_path
    'users/flag'
  end
end
```

You can store all user actions in same table and get it from there with:

```
Activity.where(user_id: uid).all
```

and you get as return array of all user actions with correct typing for every action, that allow you to implement polymorphic logic for different types of actions (as to partial path in my example, that allows you to write something like:

```
render Activity.where(user_id: uid).all
```